# info fortifyExecuteScan - Unresolved variable: List @ <fileName.java>

Tags: java, fortify

I am getting an **Unresolved variable: list** message in Fortify scan.
The message is coming from all those lines where I have used **List.of()** method in Java.

I am using Java 11.